# How to Catch ConversionFailedException?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm using `Formatter`s and `Converter`s in my Spring MVC web application. Is there a proper way to catch [`ConversionFailedException`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/4.1.5.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/convert/ConversionFailedException.html)? I want to do something else rather than having my page throw a `JasperException`.

Please note: I don't directly use a `Formatter` or `Converter`. I [configured Spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-conversion) to do that for me, somehow. So in the form, I have a `String` but using the registered `ConversionService`, it gets back to my controller's `@ModelAttribute`-annotated parameter as an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `@ExceptionHandler`, add it to your class

```
@ExceptionHandler(ConversionFailedException.class)
public void handleError(ConversionFailedException ex) {
    // handle the exception
}
```

[Reference](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc)

Comment: Ah. I understand that this is the first thing that comes to mind but I don't directly use a `Formatter` or `Converter`. I [configured Spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#core-convert-Spring-config) to do that for me, somehow. So in the form, I have a `String` but using the registered `ConversionService`, it gets back to my controller's `@ModelAttribute` annotated parameter as an object.

Comment: @Guy I will try that out in a few minutes! Thank you for your suggestion. I'll let you know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

A simple try/catch block should work.

```
try {
    // piece of code that throws the exception...
} catch (ConversionFailedException exception) {
    // you have caught the exception, do whatever you want here...
}
```

Comment: Please see [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39016477/how-to-catch-conversionfailedexception/39016529#comment65383521_39016529).

Comment: In most cases converters/formatters are not called directly from your own code, thus it's not possible to simple catch the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own `ConversionService` extending the default one and override the `convert` method to catch the conversion error and instead provide the behavior required (such as logging the conversion error).

Comment: Oh. That's a very good suggestion and is a viable option for people like me, however, `Converter`s are not only used in web applications. In my case, I'd like to throw a custom exception that pretty much represents a 404 error. That won't be a good place to throw the exception. But I get your idea. Thank you.